# PHPMailer thread/conversation in outlook not working

Tags: outlook, phpmailer

I've achieved the "conversation/thread" effect in gmail, using this code

```
$phpmailer->MessageID = $message_id;
```

and with this, in gmail all e-mails sent (with the same value in $message_id) are received in the same "conversation/thread", but this dont work in outlook, both windows 10 email app and outlook app for windows 10...

How can i achieve the same result as in gmail in outllook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't re-use the same message ID for multiple messages. There are headers specifically for creating threads, and the definitive explanation for them is [here](https://cr.yp.to/immhf/thread.html). In short, add the `Message-ID` of the message you are replying to in a `References` header, and optionally also into an `In-reply-to` header. You can create those headers in PHPMailer using `addCustomHeader()`.